# I cannot deploy a container in multiple nodes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

The problem is I face an error log = "no suitable node (1 node not …)" every time I try to deploy containers in multiple nodes.

```
placement:
        constraints:
            - node.labels.role == worker1
            - node.labels.role == manager
```

How I am going to implement a container in multiple constraints?

Comment: What you are doing is good enough, you have to have though at least one node in with the labels `role=manager` and `role=worker1`. Is that the case ? Try to run sth like `docker node inspect $(docker node ls -q) | grep -i role` to check your node roles and share it here.

Comment: I got this output:
                "role": "manager"
            "Role": "manager",
                "role": "worker1"
            "Role": "worker",

Comment: Ok in the `docker node inspect <id>` command you need to have at least a node which has both the labels of the role and also compatible OS & architecture with the image you are trying to deploy. If thats the case, please update your question with your full service config and a docker node inspect outcome of a node that you expect that should be able to host that container.